# В чём суть потоков(streamов)?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Объясните пожалуйста,в чём суть потоков(не threadов,а streamoв),зачем они нужны и.т.д. Хочу более детально понять эту тему.С ними я встретился когда изучал 
System.IO,вот что я прочитал:

- Класс File позволяет открывать, создавать, читать и записывать файлы
  целиком либо  по частям.
- Класс FileStream представляет файл и
  позволяет выполнять чтение и запись.

---

А в чём разница,зачем нужно обязательно использовать FileStream как,например, в ниже приведённом коде.И зачем нужно обязательно закрывать поток.

---

P.S На самом деле вопросов много,но решил написать по-быстрому.
Спасибо!

```
static void Main()
    {
        // Создаем новый файл в корневом каталоге диска D:
        var file = new FileInfo(@".\Test.txt");

        FileStream stream = file.Create();

        // Выводим основную информацию о созданном файле.            
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name   : {0}", file.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Attributes  : {0}", file.Attributes.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("CreationTime: {0}", file.CreationTime);

        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для удаления файла.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Закрываем FileStream.
        stream.Close();

        // Удаляем файл.
        file.Delete();

        Console.WriteLine("Файл успешно удален.");

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`Stream` представляет собой абстракцию последовательно читаемых или записываемых (бинарных) данных, и текущей позиции чтения/записи.

Под эту абстракцию подходят как файловые потоки (`FileStream`), так и потоки данных, передаваемых по сети (`NetworkStream`), данные в памяти (`MemoryStream`) и многое другое. Используя этот класс, можно обрабатывать данные, не заботясь о том, откуда они реально пришли.